How to add formulas in Modern Sharepoint page
Did anyone tried using Mathjax or Katex javascript libraries to include formulas in sharepoint page? If yes, Can I know how did you implement using SPFx? If no, Can I know your approach to write formulas in sharepoint site exactly the same format as we use in microsoft word as I find limited customisable options in sharepoint online?
I tried inserting formulas but when I copy-paste they are displayed as images itself in sharepoint page. Then I came to know we can insert formulas by latex using Mathjax or Katex libraries but I am facing issues with those. So seeking guidance for the same while creating custom web part
